Power, Power inverse and basic propoerty of the power of power (deeper understanding of power)
Before you go out, and asking why someone is asking which is the inverse of a power function.... give it a moment.
Is usual to think this:
$y = x^z$
That the inverse should be:
$y^{1/z} = x$
Then I was looking a youtube video when someone showed something very interesting.
$(-2)^2 = 4$
If we apply the inverse:
$4^{0.5} = 2$
At the same time, using the most usual power properties:
$({{-2}^{2}})^{0.5} = (-2)^{0.5*2} = (-2)^1 = -2$
As you see there is something off with the inverse function, at least with the property of:
$({x^{a}})^{b} = x^{a*b}$
This examples shows that something is off at least in my understanding of powers, that property is not true, because the result should be 2!
From where I'm just dizzy with this, so trying to go back to the power fundamentals, I can understand any integer power, is easy to interpret, but what is first weird, to say that the inverse if power of 2 is 1/2, seems here there is a convention in how to represent this part.
The point of power of 0.5 is also ask, which value squared give us a particular result, the is the obvious part, and power of 0.5 only picks the positive value.
So here some issues, what means a power that does not represents an integer? for example pi, $x^{pi}$, what it means in power terms? we can't multiply a value pi times, or at least I have not found any reason/interpretation to match this.
Any power, can be split in two, the integer part, and the decimal one, if the integer part already has a intuitive interpretation, we can ask which is the interpretation of powers from 0 to 1 that does not belongs to an integer.
So any power $z$ where $1/z$ is not an integer, what they means?.
why this is so important? Go back to the -2 case, squared and sqrt is 2, power can change the sign of a number, ${-2}^{pi}$ should be positive or negative?
How do we prove that? which is the right property of a power of a power?
Note: We agree that some equations can have more than one result, like $x^2=4$ which is -2 and 2, maybe related, just that line is very well justified.

${x^a}^b = x^{\left(a^b\right)} \neq x ^{a \cdot b}$.  $\left(x^a\right)^b = x^{a \cdot b}$.

I added some parenthesis and fixed them, to be able to see this better.

You seem to have forgotten that exponential identities have conditions.  For instance "If $x$ is a positive real number and $p/q$ is a rational number, with $p$ and $q$ integers and $q > 0$, then $x^{p/q}$ is defined as $$x^{p/q} = (x^p)^{1/q} = (x^{1/q})^p \text{."}$$  But if $x$ is not a positive real, the identity is different.

That explains a lot why I was confused, sadly but I never learned that conditions (school nor university), my understand of it is limited to the conditions you wrote, even before that, as I wrote in the question. If you can write how to get the identities for any real base and power and how to interpret it.
I have some math books, but none developed a lot this things, if you can put some references would be great! ideally until the complex plane.

I'd start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents .  Then read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms and continue reading through the section "Failure of power and logarithm identities".

mm, that has more descriptions, good start point, still seems there is a lot of missing parts to get sense to the exponent function, also seems there is no way to handle the negative exponent only with reals, complex is a need. Is there good books to get this right from the start?

It's not the negative exponents that are the problem, its the fractional exponents.  And you should expect some trouble: the real square root is only defined for nonnegative numbers.  As soon as you try to take an even root of a negative number, you're off the real line.  I don't know of a book -- this site is a good place to ask that (as a new Question).
